# How to use Android emulator with HAXM?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, emulation

I just installed Android Studio, created working virtual arm device with Android 2.3.3.

My API10 application is working.

However - emulator response is slow. I want to try Intel Emulator Accelerator.

I have Intel HAXM installed (with Android SDK Manager), my CPU supports VT-x.

I don't know:

- which system image should I use for emulation?
- which API as my application target?
- do I have to enable HAXM somewhere?

It would be nice if I could stay with API10 target.

When I configure AVD like this:

[image]

and start it - I have black screen on emulator. I have tried to turn off "Use host GPU", same result - black screen.

When I choose API Level 19 in target - I have "android" text with animation for 10 minutes.

My CPU is Core 2 Duo T9300 (up to 2.7GHz), it's pretty fast CPU (just 30-40% slower than 3GHz i7 in SuperPI benchmark).

Answer (score 1):

> which system image should I use for emulation?

If you want to use the x86 emulator, use the x86 emulation images. If you want to use the ARM emulator, use the ARM emulation images.

> do I have to enable HAXM somewhere?

"Installing" HAXM from the SDK Manager simply puts a `.exe` (Windows) or `.dmg` (OS X) on your development machine, under the `extras/` directory of your SDK. You still have to run the `.exe` or mount the disk image and run the program inside of it. This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm).

Comment: @Kamil: Did you confirm in your BIOS that VT-x extensions are enabled? They are disabled by default on many Windows notebooks.

Comment: It's enabled for sure, I'm using it in VMWare.

Comment: So... It should work with my configuration on screenshot? There is nothing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things to watch with HAXM - some info is here https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm. Also be sure to allocate enough RAM. 
Also worth trying it while NOT in VMWare?

Comment: I gave 1GB to HAXM, and I try to use 512M, or 768M, or 1GB. I mentioned VMWare just to confirm that I have VT-x working correctly. Im not trying to emulate android inside virtual machine.

Comment: and you checked that the intelhaxm process was running?